# -webkit-perspective - center content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, parallax

I'm trying to achieve a parallax effect with pure css and some centered content underneath it. For this i used the `-webkit-perspective` (perspective) rule in CSS3, in conjunction with `-webkit-transform` (transform) to get a proper effect. The parallax itself works just fine, but I can't center the content under the `height: 100vh;`/ `width 100%` parallax header.

Let me show what i've got: http://aukehuys.com/insight/

I used the method by sam beckham - here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/samdbeckham/full/OPXPNp

As you can see, my placeholder content isn't centered. At the beginning I thought I just could simply use the bootstrap framework to center the container, but it doesn't work. After realizing how the perspective rule works, this behavior is very logical. Well, let's disconnect the `parallax__cover` div with a margin value of `top: 100%` from the parallax div, but this doesn't worked either. What method could I use to get the content fixed?

Here are some code snippets, in the case you don't want to dive into my hmtl/css:

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="parallax">
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0"> <img src="img/parallax/2/1.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1"> <img src="img/parallax/2/2.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__layer__title parallax__layer__2"> <img src="img/parallax/2/title.png"></div>
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3"> <img src="img/parallax/2/3.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4"> <img src="img/parallax/2/4.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5"> <img src="img/parallax/2/5.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6"> <img src="img/parallax/2/6.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__7"> <img src="img/parallax/2/7.png"> </div>
<div class="parallax__cover">
    <div class="container">
        <section class="first-section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'> somem magical content </div>
                <div class='col-sm-6'> somem magical content </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**..and the CSS:**

```
.parallax {
-webkit-perspective: 100px;
perspective: 100px;
height: 100vh;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin-left: -1500px;}

.parallax__layer {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;}

.parallax__cover {
background: #2D112B;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin-left: -1500px;
height: 2000px;
z-index: 2;}

.parallax__layer__0 {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);}

.parallax__layer__1 {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);}

.parallax__layer__2 {
and so on;}
```

Let me know, if you need more info.

Thanks!

Comment: what a tricky layout. did you try to add width:3000px for a .parallax? So far i only came with it https://jsfiddle.net/nLpmdp4x/ , but it's not good on larger resolutions and for small devices bootstrap .container should have a fixed width.